# Order by a specific value first then show all rest in order

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below query returns list of areas i want to show the null value which is `'--- All ----'` then the rest of the values.

So out out will be

```
AreaID  AreaName
Null    '--- All ----'
1       area1
2       area2
```

etc..

**Query**

```
SELECT
dbo.Areas.AreaID,
dbo.Areas.AreaName
FROM dbo.Areas
UNION
SELECT
NULL,
'--- All ----'
ORDER BY dbo.Areas.AreaName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT AreaID,
       AreaName
FROM (
   SELECT dbo.Areas.AreaID,
          dbo.Areas.AreaName
   FROM dbo.Areas

   UNION

   SELECT NULL,
          '--- All ----'
) AS t
ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN AreaID IS NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 2
         END,
         AreaName
```

**Note:** Using a nested derived table is not required as it would have sufficed to use `ORDER BY` like you did in your query. I think though it adds to the readability of the query.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a `CASE` expression to place your `NULL` record first in the result set.  You can also add a second ordering condition to sort on the area name after this first condition has been applied.

```
SELECT
    dbo.Areas.AreaID,
    dbo.Areas.AreaName
FROM dbo.Areas
UNION
SELECT
    NULL,
    '--- All ----'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN dbo.Areas.AreaID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         dbo.Areas.AreaName
```