# ORDER BY with a specific value first

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I get --ALL-- to be at the top of my order by? I cannot use CASE WHEN in the ORDER BY clause because of the UNION. I also think the IF/ELSE  is a complication here.

This code lives in an sp that I didn't write originally. I was asked to duplicate it and add a null value (the original script didn't have any nulls).

My solution was to UNION in

```
SELECT  
    NULL as parameterValue,
    CAST('--All--' as VARCHAR(50)) AS parameterLabel
```

Now I need that Null, --All-- row to always be at the top of my results and the rest of the results to be parameterValue desc

I want to make this solution work, but I cannot figure out how to with the IF/Else:
[Order by a specific value first then show all rest in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626951/order-by-a-specific-value-first-then-show-all-rest-in-order)

````
DECLARE 
    @MaxCampaignYear int,
    @rptSection nvarchar(85) = 'Main',
    @showAll bit = 0

    SELECT 
        @MaxCampaignYear = MAX(campaignYearNum) 
    FROM 
        dbo.dimDate
    IF @rptSection = 'Main'
        SELECT
            NULL as parameterValue,
            CAST('--All--' as VARCHAR(50)) AS parameterLabel
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT
            campaignYearNum AS parameterValue,
            CAST(campaignYearNum as VARCHAR(50))  AS parameterLabel
        FROM
            dbo.dimDate
        WHERE
            (
            @showAll <> 0
            or campaignYearNum <= @MaxCampaignYear --BI_DW.dbo.udfGetCampaignYear(getdate())
            )
            and campaignYearNum > 0
        ORDER BY
            parameterValue desc
    ELSE
        SELECT
            BI_DW.dbo.udfGetCampaignYear(getdate()) as parameterValue,
            BI_DW.dbo.udfGetCampaignYear(getdate()) as parameterLabel```
````

Comment: `IF` is a logical flow operator; it can't be used inside a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a RowNum identifier in each of your unions, and then order by RowNum asc, parameterValue desc, this way you will always get --All-- first, then parameterValue desc.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            RowNum = 1,
            NULL as parameterValue,
            CAST('--All--' as VARCHAR(50)) AS parameterLabel
        UNION ALL
            RowNum = 2,
            campaignYearNum AS parameterValue,
            CAST(campaignYearNum as VARCHAR(50))  AS parameterLabel
        FROM
            dbo.dimDate
        WHERE
            (
            @showAll <> 0
            or campaignYearNum <= @MaxCampaignYear --BI_DW.dbo.udfGetCampaignYear(getdate())
            )
            and campaignYearNum > 0
        ORDER BY
            RowNum asc, parameterValue desc
```

Comment: @UnamedDBA - Yeah, this is what I usually do. Though technically you could also make the union all a derived query, then you'd be able to use that column in a `case`.

Answer (score 1):

To float your ALL to the top, update the order by to something like

```
order by
   case when '--All--' = parameterLabel
        then 1 else 2 end,
   parameterLabel
```

So, the first sort gets ALL floated to the top, THEN everything else after that.

Comment: - Thank you for this suggestion. This option will is not working because of that UNION.